# Network bandwidth usage per process Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring

Is there freely available analog from Microsoft to monitor network bandwidth usage per process on Windows Server 2003 as this is implemented with Resource Monitor on W2k8?

What I need to know is how much traffic generates particular process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of hours spent on search and installation of various network monitoring tools, it was actually found out.

To my big surprise, this is [TCPView.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) - the tool which allows to view network usage per process and then save the report.

Answer (score 3):

I am jumping on this topic as it is first on google :).
In windows 7, you can use performance monitor (perfmon.exe), in network tab you can see network activity per process :)

Comment: I think you meant Resource Monitor (resmon.exe), not Performance Monitor

Answer (score -2):

i think you can use the "task manager",at the "process" planet,choose "view"->" choose row",select "I/O write bytes","I/O read bytes","I/O other bytes",then you could know which process use ths bandwidth.

Comment: I/O = disk usage :-/